# How do I start Mosquitto MQTT broker on startup in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, systemd

I am trying to run a Mosquitto MQTT Broker on Ubuntu 16.04. I have instructions from 14.04, but since 16.04 no longer uses startup, I can't figure out how to convert to systemd.

Here are the commands for 14.04:

```
description "Mosquitto MQTT broker"
start on net-device-up
respawn
exec /usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
```

EDIT:

This is what I got to so far. When I reboot and run `systemctl status mosquitto.service` I show that mosquitto is loaded but not active:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mosquitto MQTT Broker

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/usr/sbin/mosquitto
ExecStart=/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

EDIT 2:

Ran `sudo systemctl enable mosquitto.service`. Now the error exit code is:

```
Process: 1720 ExecStart=/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Installing `sudo apt install mosquitto` on `16.04` adds the `/etc/init.d/mosquitto` script. systemd uses that script to generate `/run/systemd/generator.late/mosquitto.service`, and this is what it says:

```
# Automatically generated by systemd-sysv-generator

[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/init.d/mosquitto
Description=LSB: mosquitto MQTT v3.1 message broker
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=multi-user.target
Before=graphical.target
Before=shutdown.target
After=remote-fs.target
After=systemd-journald-dev-log.socket
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mosquitto start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/mosquitto stop
ExecReload=/etc/init.d/mosquitto reload
```

Looking inside `/etc/init.d/mosquitto` tells us that

`/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf` is already run by default

So just put your config into `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` (referenced by `mosquitto.conf`) and **enjoy**.

Being a regular systemd service, you can:

- `systemctl status mosquitto` to see its current status
- `sudo systemctl (start|stop) mosquitto` to change the status for the current session
- `sudo systemctl (enable|disable) mosquitto` to change startup behavior (without affecting the current state)

Comment: How does that file tell you that mosquitto is being run with `-c option`?

Comment: @PetrusTheron that's what happens in the `/etc/init.d/mosquitto` file with the `start` argument.

Comment: My config inside the `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d` dir seems to be ignored. How can I regenerate `/run/systemd/generator.late/mosquitto.service`?

Comment: @chris maybe it's not referenced in `/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf`? What's in there?

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that you have mosquitto running:

```
ps -aux | grep mosquitto
```

And you have this in *default.conf*:

```
listener 1883
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unit file's `ExecStart=` and `WorkingDirectory=` lines are completely wrong. Are you trying to start a config file, using the executable file(!) as its working directory?

If I understand correctly, the proper unit file would be:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mosquitto MQTT Broker
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mosquitto -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also, please don't conflate starting and enabling the unit. Read my similar answers about this:

- [start nginx on boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204488/21885)
- [Is it expected for systemd to start disabled services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39109593/857932)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to start the service with:

`sudo systemctl start mosquitto.service`